# How to display a Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, CustomType>> in a Grid using DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, datatemplate

I have text entries which have both a type and a category. To store them I use a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, ModelEntry>> ModelEntries`. Not the prettiest thing I know but works perfectly as a 2-dimensional array with string indexes. In this way for instance I can call `ModelEntries["type1"]["category2"].Content` to get the text for the corresponding entry. The number of categories and types is fixed to 3 and 4.

How can I display them in a table-like `Grid` by using a `DataTemplate`?

My goal is something like this:
[image] where the boxes of the grid would be filled with the content of the corresponding entry.

I've gotten so far to this:

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RichTextBox></RichTextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

And I don't know how to continue. Any help would be appreciated.

*Side note:* I know that since the rows and columns are fixed number I can do what I want with just more code and statically define 12 RichTextBoxes. The reason I want a DataTemplate approach is that there will be interaction with the other fields when a user clicks on a text. Browsing a Dictionary will be times easier than manually checking all statically defined RichTextBoxes.

Comment: You're itemscontrol template needs another nested itemscontrol. You have a collection within a collection so your View needs the same. Getting your headings may prove more complex with this as your model. You'll probably want to expose another collection of headings that gets built from inspecting your nested dictionary keys property.

Answer (score 0):

One of the more common mistakes made when doing WPF development is that people try to fit their view to their existing data model when it really should be the job of an intermediate layer (i.e. a view model) to mediate between the two. XAML is extremely powerful and can do some clever things but if you find yourself having to do too much work in the view or over-relying on things like converters to bend your data into a more useful form then it's usually a good indication that your view model isn't doing its job properly.

Take a step back and look at it from the other direction: you have a view in mind, what type of data do you need to allow that view to work? First of all you're displaying two things: your headers (at the top and left) and your cells, so start by creating classes in your view model for those:

```
public class CustomGridHeader
{
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
}

public class CustomGridCell
{
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public object Content { get; set; }
}
```

Now your view model is going to need a collection of things to display (both headers and cells) and a function to reference the data in your dictionary. I'll leave the translation step to you but here's enough to get started:

```
    private int _NumColumns;
    public int NumColumns
    {
        get { return this._NumColumns; }
        set { this._NumColumns = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.NumColumns); }
    }

    private int _NumRows;
    public int NumRows
    {
        get { return this._NumRows; }
        set { this._NumRows = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.NumRows); }
    }

    private object[] _GridData;
    public object[] GridData
    {
        get { return this._GridData; }
        set { this._GridData = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.GridData); }
    }

    private string[] Types = new string[] { "Type1", "Type2", "Type3" };
    private string[] Categories = new string[] { "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3" };

    private void UpdateGridData()
    {
        this.NumColumns = this.Categories.Length + 1;
        this.NumRows = this.Types.Length + 1;
        this.GridData = new object[(this.Categories.Length + 1) * (this.Types.Length + 1)];

        // set category and type headers
        for (int i=0; i<this.Categories.Length; i++)
            this.GridData[i + 1] = new CustomGridHeader { Column = i + 1, Row = 0, Header = this.Categories[i] };
        for (int i=0; i<this.Types.Length; i++)
            this.GridData[(i + 1) * this.NumColumns] = new CustomGridHeader { Column = 0, Row = i + 1, Header = this.Types[i] };

        // fill the cells
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Categories.Length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < this.Types.Length; j++)
                this.GridData[(i + 1) * this.NumColumns + j + 1] = new CustomGridCell {Column = i+1, Row = j+1, Content = String.Format("{0}/{1}", i, j)};
    }
```

Code-wise that's all you need, you now have your data in a form ready to be consumed by your view. You want to display your data in a grid, but functionally what you're really doing is displaying a list of items, so what you really should be doing is using an ItemsControl but specifying a Grid as the Panel Template. You'll also need to set the ItemContainerStyle to set the grid column and row for each element. Finally you'll need two data templates: one that specifies how your headers should be displayed and another to specify how the cells should be displayed:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GridData}" Margin="50">

    <ItemsControl.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CustomGridHeader}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CustomGridCell}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,-1,-1">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Height="50"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ItemsControl.Resources>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid
                xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
                xmlns:cmd ="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight">

                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:GridSizeBehavior Columns="4"  Rows="4"/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

</ItemsControl>
```

The only missing piece of the puzzle is GridSizeBehavior. The Grid control doesn't have "NumColumns" or "NumRows" fields, but you can effectively add it yourself with an attached behaviour (for this and other reasons I'm not convinced that Grid is the best control for this task but that's what you've asked for so that's what I'm providing):

```
public class GridSizeBehavior : Behavior<Grid>
{
    public int Columns
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Columns.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(int), typeof(GridSizeBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(0, OnColumnsChanged));

    static void OnColumnsChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behaviour = depObj as GridSizeBehavior;
        if (behaviour == null)
            return;
        behaviour.SetColumns();
    }

    private void SetColumns()
    {
        var grid = this.AssociatedObject;
        if (grid == null)
            return;
        int columns = this.Columns;
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
    }

    public int Rows
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RowsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Rows.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Rows", typeof(int), typeof(GridSizeBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(0, OnRowsChanged));

    static void OnRowsChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behaviour = depObj as GridSizeBehavior;
        if (behaviour == null)
            return;
        behaviour.SetRows();
    }

    private void SetRows()
    {
        var grid = this.AssociatedObject;
        if (grid == null)
            return;
        int Rows = this.Rows;
        grid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
    }


    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        SetColumns();
        SetRows();
    }

}
```

Put all those together and you'll get the result you're after:

[image]

The main downside to the exact implementation shown here is that the view won't update automatically in response to changes to your original dictionaries, but given that Dictionary doesn't support collection change notification that was never going to happen anyway. Yes, you could have done all this entirely in your view using converters to enumerate your columns and rows and bind to your dictionary data directly, but at the end of the day you would have found that your code would have pretty much matched what I've done here in the view model anyway, so you may as well do it there in a form that's easy to debug and unit test.